# Filtering datagridview by textbox change

Tags: c#, winforms, linq-to-sql, filtering

Using Linq to sql through bindingsource control in WinForms, I could not get this to work:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            productBindingSource.Filter = string.Format("ProductName LIKE '*{0}*'", textBox1.Text);
            MessageBox.Show("Changed");
}
        NorthwindDataContext dc;
        private void FrmFilter_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // create new data context
        dc = new NorthwindDataContext();

        // set the binding source data source to the full order table
        var qry = (from p in dc.Products select p).ToList();
        this.productBindingSource.DataSource = dc.GetTable<Product>();
    }
```

When I type some letter in the textbox nothing happens in the datagridview.
Thanks for advices ...

Comment: It's highly unlikely your data source has a dataGridViewTextBoxColumn2  column, that looks like it belongs to the DataGridView column.  Try filtering on the column of the data source that your datagridview is using.

Comment: tried this: this.productBindingSource.Filter = string.Format("**ProductName** like '%{0}%'", textBox1.Text.Trim().Replace("'", "''")); Nothing changed.

Answer (score 3):

Try changing your code to look like this:

```
NorthwindDataContext dc;

private void FrmFilter_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  dc = new NorthwindDataContext();
  this.productBindingSource.DataSource = dc.GetTable<Product>();
  productDataGridView.DataSource = productBindingSource;
}

private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  this.productBindingSource.Filter = string.Format("ProductName LIKE '*{0}*'",
                                     textBox1.Text);
}
```

Make sure your TextChanged event is wired up and actually running.  Also, I took qry out of the example since you weren't using it anywhere in the posted code.

---

**older edits:**

You shouldn't have to reset the DataSource on the grid.

Try changing it to this:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  if (textBox1.Text == string.Empty) {
    productBindingSource.RemoveFilter();
  } else {
    productBindingSource.Filter = string.Format("ProductName LIKE '*{0}*'", _
                                  textBox1.Text);
  }
}
```

I would avoid worrying about replacing those special characters at the moment.  Get the filter working first.

---

Here is a working example with just a DataGridView and a TextBox on a form:

```
private DataTable dt = new DataTable("Test");
private BindingSource bs;

public Form1() {
  InitializeComponent();

  dt.Columns.Add("ProductName", typeof(string));

  DataRow dr1 = dt.NewRow();
  dr1["ProductName"] = "One A";
  dt.Rows.Add(dr1);

  DataRow dr2 = dt.NewRow();
  dr2["ProductName"] = "One B";
  dt.Rows.Add(dr2);

  DataRow dr3 = dt.NewRow();
  dr3["ProductName"] = "Two A";
  dt.Rows.Add(dr3);

  DataRow dr4 = dt.NewRow();
  dr4["ProductName"] = "Two B";
  dt.Rows.Add(dr4);

  bs = new BindingSource(dt, null);
  dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;
}

private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  if (textBox1.Text == string.Empty) {
    bs.RemoveFilter();
  } else {
    bs.Filter = string.Format("ProductName LIKE '*{0}*'", textBox1.Text);
  }
}
```

Comment: Updated with the proper wild cards.

Comment: sorry, I tried this without success, The datagrid content remain the same.

Comment: @AlphaBird Just to check, but is your DataGridView using productBindingSource as it's DataSource already?  It should be.

Comment: Yes, My DataGridView is using productBindingSource as its DataSource already, and when I load the form datagridview is full, thank you for your efforts Lars ... Please check the newly added code above.

Comment: Sorry Lars, I tried your example, I can fill datagrid but not filter rows, something is wrong since you said that it is a working example.

Comment: @AlphaBird Does the TextChanged event even fire?  Put a debug breaker on that event and see if the filter changes.  I strongly suspect the event isn't hooked up.

Comment: Yes, that's right TextChanged event was not firing, I tried the example, now it is filtering, but when I returned to my case I verified that the event is firing but nothing is filtered.

Comment: @AlphaBird At this point, it's pretty hard to offer more help.  You will have to compare the differences between the example that works and the code that doesn't.

Comment: Thank you very much Lars for your help, I have placed a message box like what is updated above, I receive the messagebox but the datagrid doesn't change.

Answer (score 1):

this work just fine for me!

```
this.productBindingSource.Filter = null;
```